# Hadoop - ODBC with HBASE without HIVE

Tags: web-services, hadoop, odbc, hive, hbase

I would like to know if it is possible to develop a bridge beetween Hadoop (HBASE) and a ODB, for example a web service. (so, without using HIVE)

Hadoop without HIVE <-> Web service <->(ODBC flow)<->Database

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can build a bridge using the Simba Engine SDK. We would be pleased to have a call to discuss.

Please let me know a time that works.

Tom Newton

Comment: In fact, you can look at the HBase ODBC driver from Simba (see here: http://www.simba.com/connectors/apache-hbase-odbc), that may solve your problem already.

Comment: Ok why not, but is there a free solution I could use?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a free solution, to my knowledge if you want ODBC access to HBase the Simba driver is the only solution. You can trial it for 30 days for free to see if it'll work for you.

Comment: Yes, but I think I can develop something similar to SIMBA ODBC driver don't you think ? Because as I said, I prefer a free solution.